# mysql query show most liked post

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count most liked post in a week from data. But my mined was confused how can i count it. I also just want to show just first most popular liked post in a week. I did a search for a sample answer, but I did not find any results. Could you help me, please. The table looks like this, the time is unixtimestamp

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  post_id   | date       |  user_id   | post_id_fk |
+------------+-------------------------+------------+
|     32     | 1535624966 |   21       |   148      |
|     33     | 1535624990 |   68       |   148      |
|     34     | 1535625007 |   99       |   758      |
|     35     | 1535625022 |   12       |   148      |
|     36     | 1535625039 |   43       |   148      |
+------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

The query should be count `post_id_fk` in a week using date unixtimestamp and print the most liked `post_id_fk`.

I have tryed like the following query but it is counting just a rows but i need most popular `post_id_fk` and also it should be show in a week.

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS postLikeCount FROM post_like 
WHERE post_id_fk = post_id_fk") 
or die(mysqli_error($this->db));    
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);  
return $row['postLikeCount'];
```

Comment: So do you want a report showing all weeks?  I'm not sure I like using UNIX timestamps in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to report weekly most popular liked post id.

Comment: Do you specify the week in the year, or is it most popular post from the past (most recent) week?

Comment: @AmmoPT It is most popular post from the past (most recent) week.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky query in pre MySQL 8+, because you need to aggregate twice; once to find the counts per post and week, and then again to find the greatest count among those groups.  To add to the confusion, we also have to convert UNIX timestamps to a date format which we can easily use.

```
SELECT
    t1.yearweek,
    t1.post_id_fk,
    t1.cnt AS max_count
FROM
(
    SELECT
        YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) AS yearweek,
        post_id_fk,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM post_like
    GROUP BY
        YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)),
        post_id_fk

) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT yearweek, MAX(cnt) AS max_cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) AS yearweek,
            post_id_fk,
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM post_like
        GROUP BY
            YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)),
            post_id_fk
    ) t
    GROUP BY yearweek
) t2
    ON t1.yearweek = t2.yearweek AND t1.cnt = t2.max_cnt;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: @Azzo Try using the demo I included; I'm pretty sure this is correct.  It would be a lot more work to come up with more robust test data, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, and what you're asking really belongs in a separate question.  It should be easy for you to look up how to execute a MySQL query from PHP.

Comment: can i ask a question about your answer please ?

Comment: Your code is confused me. Can you check this demo please: https://rextester.com/DUZ42438 . In this demo you can see normaly 1. post should be `post_id_fk 39` but it is showing `post_id_fk 148` . The `39 max_count` higher then `148 max_count` .

Comment: @Azzo Check [this updated demo](https://rextester.com/QLQ74860) and you will see that there are only two distinct year weeks in your data set, and, in fact, posts 148 and 39 have the highest counts from each of the two weeks.

Comment: I understood, but i get an error sometimes like this: `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'testServer.post_like.post_type' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` I used your codes like this: https://rextester.com/CLRZV29661

Comment: Then you're not running my answer, because my query would never generate this error.  However you are using my answer, it is wrong.  Stop selecting non aggregate columns while using `GROUP BY`, and the error should go away.  You might want to ask a new question at this point.

Comment: Your answer is not giving this error in localhost and some server. But i try to use your code in two different server. Your code is working fine first server but give me an error another server.

Comment: _You are not using my query, because my query has no posttype column_.  You should open a new question at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I know this already has an answer but doesn't this query do what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS postLikeCount, date, post_id_fk 
FROM post_like
WHERE
    date BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day))) 
    AND FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP) 
group by post_id_fk
order by postLikeCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to group the results by the post_id `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM post_like WHERE /* here condition for week */ GROUP BY post_id SORT BY count DESC`